# Unable to find last row of 2nd workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to find the last used row on a 2nd workbook and I keep getting an `Application-defined or object-defined error` on my `alastRow` variable..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim xRet As Boolean
    Dim Name As String
    Dim srcBk As Workbook, srcWS As Worksheet, testWS As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, cR As Range, testRng As Range
    Dim mm, nn
    Dim arrLoc
    Dim alastRow As Long
    
    
    arrLoc = Array("    A-3", "    A-4", "    A-5", "    A-6", "    A-7", "    A-8", "    A-9", "    A-10", "    A-11", "    A-12", _
                   "    B-1", "    B-2", "    B-3", "    B-4", "    B-5", "    B-6", "    B-7", "    B-8", "    B-9", "    B-10", "    B-11", "    B-12", _
                   "    C-1", "    C-2", "    C-3", "    C-4", "    C-5", "    C-6", "    C-7", "    C-8", "    C-9", "    C-10", "    C-11", "    C-12", _
                   "    D-1", "    D-2", "    D-3", "    D-4", "    D-5", "    D-6", "    D-7", "    D-8", "    D-9", "    D-10", "    D-11", "    D-12", _
                   "    E-1", "    E-2", "    E-3", "    E-4", "    E-5", "    E-6", "    E-7", "    E-8", "    E-9", "    E-10", "    E-11", "    E-12", _
                   "    F-1", "    F-2", "    F-3", "    F-4", "    F-5", "    F-6", "    F-7", "    F-8", "    F-9", "    F-10", "    F-11", "    F-12", _
                   "    G-1", "    G-2", "    G-3", "    G-4", "    G-5", "    G-6", "    G-7", "    G-8", "    G-9", "    G-10", "    G-11", "    G-12", _
                   "    H-1", "    H-2", "    H-3", "    H-4", "    H-5", "    H-6", "    H-7", "    H-8", "    H-9", "    H-10", "    H-11", "    H-12")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\BUTTON PRESS TO OPEN", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
        If FileToOpen <> False Then
   
            Name = CStr(FileToOpen)
            xRet = IsWorkBookOpenNow(Name)
            
                Set srcBk = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
                Set testWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
                Set srcWS = srcBk.Worksheets(1)
                Set testRng = testWS.Columns(1)
                alastRow = srcBk.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'ERROR HERE
    
            srcBk.Sheets(1).Range("B:I").UnMerge                                     'open user selected file and unmerge columns
            testWS.Range("B1").Value = srcWS.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Value           
            testWS.Range("B3").Value = srcWS.Range("A1:A50").Find(" ", , xlValues).Offset(-1, 0).Value          'find the first cell containing 1 space

            For Each c In srcWS.Range("A1:A" & alastRow).Cells                    
                mm = Application.Match(c.Value, arrLoc, 0)                           'find cell value containing anything in array
                    
                    If Not IsError(mm) Then
                        nn = Application.Match(c.Value, testRng, 0)                  
                        Set cR = testWS.Cells(nn, 2)                                 
                        cR.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value                              
                    End If
                
            Next c
            
                With testWS.Range("B4:B100")
                    .WrapText = True
                    .RowHeight = 15
                    .ColumnWidth = 27.43
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
                End With
       
            If xRet <> True Then
                srcBk.Close False
            End If

        End If
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

I've tried

`For Each c In srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(1, 1), srcWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).End(xlUp).Cells` and

`alastRow = srcWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and

`alastRow = srcBk.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

I'm getting the same error for everything.  If I define the range `srcWS.range("A1:A100")` it works just fine.

One thing I did notice is the workbook this macro is located has 1048576 rows and the workbook I'm trying to get data from has 65536.  I wouldn't think it would matter, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code for the line that gives the error.

```
alastRow = rcBk.Worksheets(1).Cells(srcBk.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

or

```
With srcBk.Worksheets(1)
    alastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

The difference is in `srcBk.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count` which takes the measurement in the same worksheet in which you want to find the last row. Without specifying the sheet the ActiveSheet will be used. In most cases that makes no difference because all worksheets created by your Excel version have the same number of rows. In this case, however, you appear to be looking at a worksheet which was created by another, older version of Excel which has fewer rows and the attempt to address a row that doesn't exist causes the error.

Comment: Ahh, interesting.  Good piece of knowledge to know.  Your first suggestion worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: Great! Thanks for then feedback. The second solution is exactly the same code just using different syntax which, to me, is more transparent and probably shorter. In your code, the next line of code would go into the same `With` statement (unless your *Worksheet(1)* is different from your *Sheet(1)* which demonstrates both my points, better readability and greater brevity.

Comment: Nope they're the same, that does make more sense. I don't quite have the most efficient writing yet, I'm still missing things like that.  Thanks for the second suggestion!